# Did the Bahraini uprising of 2011 accomplish anything?

Tags: middle-east, bahrain

The Bahraini uprising that occurred back in 2011 was considered a [failure by various people](http://openaccess.city.ac.uk/13046/1/Manuscript-notanonymousREVISED.pdf) especially since this act of civil disobedience didn't lead to democracy or the [abdication of King Hamad](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2011/feb/18/bahrain-mourners-call-downnfall-monarchy), a key goal of the protests. However, did the uprising accomplish anything or succeed in any of their goals in spite of not achieving their main goal?

Comment: Nothing that I could find. But I might have just not found it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bahrain uprising pushed the royal dynasty to take very dangerous steps

1. the gov. propaganda tried to show that it was a Shia vs Sunni struggle and  tried to show that Shia are loyal to Iran.
   Every Bahraini knows this is farfetched , Especially since the Leader of the uprising is Sunni and the corruption of Prime Minister of Bahrain (who is in office since Bahrain independence in 1969 )[Khalifa bin Salman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khalifa_bin_Salman_Al_Khalifa)
2. Bahrain hired Mercenaries from Pakistan to control the crowds in the streets and hired western 'security' guards to protect the royal family. which totally disconnected the royal family from any supporters in the ground.
3. Saudi intervention by Sending Saudi Army made Bahrain officially a client state, which Bahraini totally reject.
4. Bahrain government started giving Bahraini citizenship to a  influx of Sunni migrants (from Yemen , Syria , Egypt especially those with expertise in gov. security establishment ) in order to have some loyal class ( a lot of corruption is also involved in selling the nationality since it gives access to GCC countries)
   however Bahrain is not an oil exporter and totally dependent on Saudi support and giveaways and the local economy can not support such influx , leading to more alienation of authentic Bahraini and economic hardship which in turn leads to more radicalization.

So the uprising stretched the royal family control over Bahrain beyond its limit, made the royal family more dependent on US support, and courting Israel to guarantee their support in the US , which leads to more resentment from Bahraini citizens and loss of respect among Arabs in General

the pressure is cooking